# Both a page loop and posts loop on the same page

Tags: loop, get-posts

I'm trying to get first the content of a single page (the one that is queried), and then in a small section below i want to display the title of my bloggposts as a "Latest News" section.

The problem is that if i first use `<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>` to get the page content. And then try to use `$posts_array = get_posts( $args );` to get the blogposts i just get the heading of the page twice. Obviously the `get_posts` function takes on the id of the page instead of looping through the blogposts. Is there a way to tell get_posts to search for the first 5 blogpost id's and not the current page id?

Grateful for all answers, suggestions, tips or hints :)

here is my code:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <div class="mcenter">   
                <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?> role="article">
                    <header class="entry-header">
                        <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

                    <div class="entry-content">
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                        <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link">' . __( 'Pages:', 'monster' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
                        <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'monster' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
                    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
                </article><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->
            </div>
            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

            <?php 
                $args = array( 
                    'numberposts'       => 5,
                    'offset'            => 0,
                    'category'          => ,
                    'orderby'           => 'post_date',
                    'order'             => 'DESC',
                    'include'           => ,
                    'exclude'           => ,
                    'meta_key'          => ,
                    'meta_value'        => ,
                    'post_type'         => 'post',
                    'post_mime_type'    => ,
                    'post_parent'       => ,
                    'post_status'       => 'publish');

                $posts_array = get_posts( $args ); 

            ?> 
            <div id="news">
                <div id="news-roll" class="mcenter">
                    <h3><?php _e('Siste nytt:', 'monster'); ?></h3> 
                    <?php 
                    $count = 1;
                    foreach ($posts_array as $monster_news) { 
                        setup_postdata($monster_news);

                        if ($count == 1) {
                            echo '<p class="first-news">'; 
                        } else {
                        echo '<p>';
                        }

                        the_title();

                        echo '</p>';

                     } 
                     $count = null;
                     ?>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: _Obviously the get_posts function takes on the id of the page_ - this is very far from obvious, `get_posts()` is completely unaware of context and should only use arguments you pass to it. What exactly do you get in `$posts_array`?

Comment: oh.. I just assumed this because i got the same title as a result in both cases. it turns out when i use the_title(); it gives me the title from the first page loop, to the get_posts call.

So when i ran print_r on $monster_news i got the right data. I guess i have to point to a individual variable to get to the title out of the array? or should i be able to use the_title();

Comment: the result i get is this: stdClass Object ( [ID] => 1 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2012-03-06 13:29:43 [post_date_gmt] => 2012-03-06 13:29:43 [post_content] => Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start blogging! [post_title] => Hello world! [post_excerpt] => [post_status] => publish [comment_status] => open [ping_status] => open [post_password] => [post_name] => hello-world [to_ping] => [pinged] => [post_modified] => .... and so on :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
foreach ($posts_array as $monster_news) { 
                    setup_postdata($monster_news);
```

To:

```
foreach ($posts_array as $post) { 
                    setup_postdata($post);
```

It seems `setup_postdata()` actually doesn't modify `$post` itself (which was news to me).

PS also loose empty `,` in array... I am not sure how it actually works for you with that.

Comment: your correct in both cases :) just figured it out my self. But this confirms it. :) I did not think that it was important to use '$post' rather than just any $var.

I also got an error trying to run it with the empty variables in the array. forgot to update my question :)